# Any way to publish Asp.Net (not Core) web app on Mac

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio, azure

Is there any way to publish Asp.Net (not Core) web app in Visual Studio for Mac to Azure? There is a button 'publish...' for Core apps, but I can't find it for .net framework apps.

Comment: non-core ASP.NET will not run on Mac or Linux - only on Windows.

Comment: I rather say ASP.NET 4.x are not considered "officially" supported on Mac or Linux. You should stick to ASP.NET Core. There is no ".NET Framework" there.

Comment: That's not true guys, you can run asp.net apps on mac.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible.

Checkout [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/96831/visual-studio-2017-mac-community-edition-no-publis.html).